# Packer amazon-ebs : AuthFailure

Tags: amazon-web-services, packer

For some reason Packer fails to authenticate to AWS, using plain aws client works though, and my environment variables are correctly set:

```
AWS_ROLE_SESSION_NAME=...
AWS_SESSION_TOKEN=...
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=...
AWS_ROLE=...
AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=...
AWS_CLI=...
AWS_ACCOUNT=...
AWS_SECURITY_TOKEN=...
```

I am using authentication using aws saml, and Packer gives me the following:

```
Error querying AMI: AWS was not able to validate the provided access credentials (AuthFailure)
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem lies within the way Packer authenticates with AWS.

Packer is written in go and uses goamz for authentication. When creating a config using aws saml, a couple of files are generated in ~/.aws : config and credentials.

Turns out this credentials file takes precedence over the environment variables, so if these credentials are incorrect and you rely on your environment variables, you will get the same error.

Since aws-saml needs aws_access_key_id and aws_secret_access_key to be defined, deleting the credentials file would not suffice in this case.

We had to copy these values into ~/.aws/config and delete the credentials file, then Packer was happy to use our environment variables.

A ticket has been raised in github for goamz so AWS CLI and Packer can have the same authenticating behavior, feel free to vote it up if you have the issue too : https://github.com/mitchellh/goamz/issues/171